# Oracle sql query needed to display count(*) values under other columns of table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one requirement from Oracle sql which will display data from query and have output some what like below:-

- First case:-Count(*) is between 0-2 then count(*) value should be    under 0-2 column
- Second case:-Count(*)  is between 2-4 then count(*)    value should be under 2-4 column
- Third case:-Count(*)  is between    4-24 then count(*) value should be under 4-24 column
- Fourth    case:-Count(*) is between 24-48 then count(*) value should be under    24-48  column
- Fifth case:-Count(*) is >48 or 'grater than 48' then    count(*) value should be under > 48 column

query:

```
Select a,b,Count(*),0-2,2-4,4-24,24-48,>48
from Table
where id=4
group by a,b,0-2,2-4,4-24,24-48,>48;
```

Sample output for id=4 and here let say count is 6 here

```
Count(*)|0-2|2-4|4-24|24-48|>48|
--------|---|---|----|-----|---|
6       |0  |0  |6   |0    |0  |
```

Note 0-2,2-4,4-24,24-48,>48 are column names

Comment: That's great that you have a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bunch of `case` statements:

```
Select a, b,
       (case when Count(*) < 2 then count(*) else 0 end) as "0-1",
       (case when count(*) >= 2 and count(*) < 4 then count(*) else 0 end) as "2-3",
       . . .
from Table
where id = 4
group by a, b;
```

Note:  `between` is inclusive in SQL.  I assume that you don't want a count of "2" to appear in two columns.